# How would I create a PostgreSQL database using "CREATE DATABASE" over an ODBC connection using PyODBC?

Tags: postgresql, pyodbc, unixodbc

I am attempting to create a PostgreSQL 12.1 database (not a schema) using the `CREATE DATABASE` statement from a Python 3.7.5 program connecting to a PostgreSQL 12.1 instance as user postgres over UnixODBC and using the PyODBC module, all running on Ubuntu 19.10. My program runs a loop that reads lines from a SQL DDL script, splitting SQL statements on the semicolon character. It logs the following errors:

```
16:15:20 ERROR    Error executing statement 'CREATE DATABASE "TestV1" WITH OWNER = postgres': ('25001', '[25001] ERROR: CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block;\nError while executing the query (1) (SQLExecDirectW)')
16:15:20 CRITICAL Unable to create objects: ('25001', '[25001] ERROR: CREATE DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block;\nError while executing the query (1) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

My SQL DDL script begins with the following line:
`CREATE DATABASE "TestV1" WITH OWNER = postgres;`

I've had success with `CREATE SCHEMA` in the same context, but not with `CREATE DATABASE`. As well, I cannot seem to find any answers here related to `CREATE DATABASE` on PostgreSQL specifically. I can create a database from the shell command line using `createdb`. I have tried setting AUTOCOMMIT on within the SQL DDL script, but that does not work.

Comment: Can you try setting `autocommit=True` in `pyodbc.connect()`?

Comment: I've tried setting `AutoCommit=True` in the connection string and it turns out to be the default, so the result is the same as if I left it out.

Comment: "[autocommit=True] turns out to be the default" - No. The Python DBAPI clearly specifies that the default must be `autocommit=False`.

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks for that. I was able to verify that autocommit is false by default when I tried removing my calls to the commit() and rollback() methods and was subsequently surprised to find my data missing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is best to issue the `createdb` command from the Bash shell and be done with it. I can then connect to the newly created database from ODBC. Rinse and repeat for each database to be created and populated.

Comment: Good on you for the workaround. Shame this doesn't work through the interface.